# Linearity of pushforward of tangent vectors and differentiability

Tags: calculus, derivatives, differential-geometry

Let $f:U\to V$ be a continuous map of open subsets of Euclidean spaces $U\subset\mathbb R^m,V\subset\mathbb R^n$. Suppose:

1. For every differentiable curve $\gamma$ in $U$ based at $p\in U$ the composite $f\circ \gamma$ is a differentiable curve in $V$ based at $fp$.
2. There's a well-defined assignment $\gamma^\prime(0)\mapsto (f\circ \gamma)^\prime(0)$ which is moreover a linear map $\mathbb R^m=\mathrm T_pU\to \mathrm T_{fp}V=\mathbb R^n$.

Does it follow that $f$ is differentiable at $p$?

Example 3.3 of Kriegl and Michor's *The Convenient Setting of Global Analysis* provides a non-differentiable function $\mathbb R^2\to \mathbb R^2$ satisfying the first condition, but it does not seem to satisfy the second.

Comment: I guess implicit in (2) is the assumption that there even is such an assignment, i.e. that $(f\circ \gamma)'(0)$ depends only upon $\gamma'(0)$?

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis yes I completely missed that. Thank you!

Comment: Duplicate of [Differentiability of composition with every path implies differentiability](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2170970/differentiability-of-composition-with-every-path-implies-differentiability) (no vote to close because of active bounty)

Comment: @Dap if you post this as an answer remarking that same proof works with any Euclidean space as the codomain of $f$ I will happily award you the bounty.