# Possible condition on locally Euclidean subset of Euclidean space to be embedded submanifold II

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

Given a locally Euclidean (locally homeomorphic to some Euclidean space) subset $X\subset\mathbb R^n$ and $p\in X$, let $\widetilde{\mathrm{T}}_pX$ denote the *tangent set* of $X$ at $p$, namely the set of derivatives of differentiable curves in $X$ based at $p$.

Suppose for all $p\in X$ we have that $\widetilde{\mathrm{T}}_pX$ is a linear subspace of $\mathbb R^n$ of dimension $\dim_pX$. Does it follow that $X\subset\mathbb R^n$ is an embbeded differentiable submanifold?

**Added.** Here's a thought. Perhaps we can locally construct an exponential map which is a *diffeomorphism* between a neighborhood of the tangent plane and a neighborhood of $p$ in $X$. Using this diffeomorphism we can move between a differentiable structure on $X$ and the differentiable functions defined on the aforementioned neighborhood of the tangent plane.

[image]

Comment: I think this and [your other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2607121/linearity-of-pushforward-of-tangent-vectors-and-differentiability) are equivalent (via $M$ being the graph of $f$). No idea on the answer, though.

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis could you please elaborate on the equivalence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Construct a function $f:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R$ by putting a smooth bump of height $2^{-n}$ supported in a ball of radius $2^{-3n}$ around $(0,2^{-n}),$ for each positive integer $n.$ This function is smooth except at $(0,0).$ Let $X$ be the graph $\{(x,y,f(x,y))\}.$ The projection onto the first two-co-ordinates is a homeomorphism onto $\mathbb R^2,$ and restricts to a diffeo from $X\setminus\{(0,0,0)\}$ to $\mathbb R^2\setminus\{(0,0)\}$ so the tangent sets are good except possibly at $(0,0,0).$ For $(0,0,0),$ for each desired tangent vector $(x,y,0)$ not parallel to $(0,1,0)$ we can take a straight line $(tx,ty,0)$ ($t$ small) as the tangent curve. And for $(0,1,0)$ we can take $(t^2,t,0).$

Answer (score 0):

[This MO answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/291394/69037) also implies a negative answer to my question. The second subset constructed there does not admit a differentiable structure making its inclusion into a differentiable embedding.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qXfdD.jpg) is a rough drawing and [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/291392/is-the-space-of-tangents-actually-the-tangent-space#comment722819_291394) is a rough description of why this example satisfies the condition in question.